# Thoughts on this Endless RecyclerView implementation?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am looking to implement an endless RecyclerView which will load more images from a DB server when the user reaches the end of the list.

If the total number of images stored on the DB server is 5000 and the app will retrieve 50 new images each time would this cause the app to eventually crash after a while?

I would imagine the ArrayList used to hold the images would grow too large and consume all of the heap memory. The type of the list is byte array by the way.

What would be a way to overcome this issue?

What I have in mind is to set the top portion of the ArrayList to null when the user reaches the end of the list and to restore the images from the DB server when the user scrolls up.

Comment: save the image on disk amd store the path in list and load the images using glide

Comment: I have thought about saving the images onto the disk but if the number of images is far too large the internal storage of the device would not be sufficient. I think a better alternative is to retrieve it from the server and to hold it in memory.

Comment: As far as i know, internal storage is much larger when compared to RAM, and consuming it doesnt even caue OOM most of the times. You must design a proper algorithm to delete the images once their ise is done.